# How does sqlite-net update method work?

Tags: c#, sqlite, orm, windows-runtime, sqlite-net

https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net

How does Update method from this library write data to DB? Does it rewrite all columns or just updated ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for the `Update` method on `SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1` which is the same as for Windows Runtime:

> Updates all of the columns of a table using the specified object except for its primary key.

And the query executed is built from this line of LINQ code:

```
var q = string.Format ("update \"{0}\" set {1} where {2} = ? ", map.TableName, string.Join (",", (from c in cols
            select "\"" + c.Name + "\" = ? ").ToArray ()), pk.Name);
```

SQL will then update the columns whether the values are different or not.

If you want to update only changed columns you could loop through all the columns, compare the value(s) passed in to the appropriate column, and if they are different, run some update code by creating your own query statement.